# How do I create a Lookup table in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a list of servernames

- PARDC1 EURDC2 EURDC3 USADC1 USADC22 CHNDC1 CHNDC2

I have created a hashtable to pick the first 3 letters of servernames, and classify it in a region.

- PAR = EMEA
- EUR = EMEA
- USA = NAM
- CHN = APAC

I want to use the lookup table to classify all servers in appropriate regions.

How do I go about doing this in Powershell ?

Comment: $servers = (gc C:\temp\list.txt) -split ' '
$hash=@{}
$hash["PAR"]='EMEA'
$hash["EUR"]='EUR'
$hash["EUR"]='EMEA'
$hash["USA"]='NAM'
$hash["CHN"]='APAC'

$keys= $hash.keys; 

foreach ($server in $servers) { 
    foreach ($key in $keys) { 
        
        if ($server -match $key) {
        
            [PSCustomObject]@{ComputerName=$server; Region=$hash[$key]}
        } 
    } 
}

Comment: Sorry Sunny, cannot give you an asnwer in proper code format b/c of downvotes

Answer (score 2):

You can create an empty hash table with

```
$hash = @{}
```

You can then add entries to it with

```
$hash['foo'] = $bar
```

or

```
$hash.foo = $bar
```

and access them the same way later again.